# PyQt QComboBox.setEditText leaves the entered text selected/highlighted; how to unhighlight?

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, qcombobox

**UPDATE3 - SOLVED with reservations,** please see my solution below; leaving it open since the cause of the problem is unclear, and I don't know how robust the solution is.

---

**UPDATE1:** here's the short short version.

Currently, after .setEditText on a QComboBox, I get this:

[image]

so the next thing you type will overwrite 'Team '.

But the desired effect is this (unhighlighted / unselected), so that the next thing you type will be appended to 'Team ' instead of overwriting it:

[image]

Thanks for any help.  The rambling details are below, which is the original post:

### (this is all PyQt 5.4)

**UPDATE2:**
Apparently python doesn't think anything is actually selected:

```
    self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setText("Team ")
    print("selected text:"+self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().selectedText())
```

prints "selected text:" and nothing else.  To make sure that's working:

```
self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setText("Team ")
self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setSelection(0,4)
print("selected text:"+self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().selectedText())
```

prints "selected text:Team"

So that might be why many of the methods that affect selection are not working as expected (.deselect(), .setSelection(5,5), etc, and even some of the other methods give unexpected behavior, i.e. cursorForward(False,1) or cursorBackward(False,1) and such.

**Original post:**

This is for a radio log GUI, so keyboard interactions must be minimal and intuitive.  openNewEntryForm (below) is called as a slot from a pushbutton on the main application GUI window:

```
self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.openNewEntryDialog)
```

It can also be called using a keyPressEvent in the same class:

```
def keyPressEvent(self,event):
    if type(event)==QKeyEvent:
        print("QKeyEvent:"+str(event.key()))
        if event.key()==Qt.Key_T:
            self.openNewEntryDialog('t')
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

Here's the method in question:

```
def openNewEntryDialog(self,key=None):
    self.entryDialog=newEntryDialog()
    if key=='t':
        self.entryDialog.ui.to_fromField.setCurrentIndex(1)
        self.entryDialog.ui.teamField.setFocus()
        self.entryDialog.ui.teamField.setEditText("Team ")

    if self.entryDialog.exec_():
        self.newEntry(self.entryDialog.getValues()) # adds the log entry
```

so, the intended key press sequence is (from the main application GUI window):

a single keyboard press of 't' will open the entryForm, set the to_fromField to index 1 (which happens to be "TO"), give focus to teamField (also a QComboBox), set its text to "Team " and set itself up so that the very next keypress will appear as the text following "Team " in teamField.

So, starting from the main app GUI again, the plan is that typing 't3' should open the new entry window, set the to_fromField to "TO", and set the teamField to "Team 3", ready for a keypress of the tab key to move on to the next field in the entryForm.

The problem is that the `teamField.setEditText("Team ")` call leaves all of the text highlighted/selected, so that a subsequent key press of `'3'` would replace `"Team "` with `"3"`; I'm looking for a way to unhighlight/unselect "Team " but leave the cursor active at the right of that string, so that the subsequent key press of `'3'` would make the entire string `"Team 3"`.

Ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the line-edit of the combo box, and then remove the selection:

```
    self.entryDialog.ui.teamField.setEditText("Team ")
    self.entryDialog.ui.teamField.lineEdit().deselect()
```

**UPDATE**:

The above code is correct, but it seems that the dialog will then clobber it when it initialises the focus handling for its child widgets after it is shown. If a dialog is opened with `exec()`, it will start its own event-loop, and some events (including focus events) will only be processed *after* it is fully shown. This is why it may appear that some changes made to child widgets *before* the dialog is shown are being ignored.

One way to work around this is to use a single-shot timer to ensure the changes are only attempted *after* the dialog is shown.

So add a method to the entry dialog class something like this:

```
    def resetUI(self, key):
        if key == 't':
            self.ui.to_fromField.setCurrentIndex(1)
            self.ui.teamField.setFocus()
            self.ui.teamField.setEditText('Team ')
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.ui.teamField.lineEdit().deselect)
```

and then use it like this:

```
def openNewEntryDialog(self, key=None):
    self.entryDialog = newEntryDialog()
    self.entryDialog.resetUI(key)
    if self.entryDialog.exec_():
        self.newEntry(self.entryDialog.getValues())
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  Thanks for the lead on using the lineEdit() but it seems like a lot of the QLineEdit class methods aren't behaving as expected.  setSelection seems to work as long as you give it a range of one or more characters; home(False) and end(False) and deselect() all leave the text highlighted/selected.  I'll keep trying various methods of the lineEdit object.

Comment: interesting, thanks.  So, do you think the solution I stumbled on is still subject to a race condition and therefore is not robust?

Comment: @TomGrundy. Hard to say: you'd have to trace the code in the Qt source to see exactly what happens and in what order. However, I would say that your current solution doesn't really solve the original question, because it doesn't fully clear the selection. It also relies on specific knowledge of the entered text (e.g. its length), and so is not a generic solution.

Comment: hmm - very true on both counts.  Anyway thanks for the solution and for the clues that led to the other incidental solution.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED with reservations,** see UPDATE3 in the original post.

So, with the initial text all highlighted, tests show that it didn't actually think anything was selected.  This solution was just stumbled upon by trial and error, fiddling with setting and clearing focus, selecting text and trying deselect:

```
def openNewEntryDialog(self,key=None):
        self.entryForm=newEntryDialog()
        if key=='t':
            self.entryForm.ui.to_fromField.setCurrentIndex(1)
            self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setFocus()
            self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setText("Team  ")
            self.entryForm.ui.teamField.lineEdit().setSelection(5,1)
```

Notice there are two spaces after 'Team' and the second one is intentionally selected.  Then the very next keypress will overwrite that second space; that is basically the desired behavior.

Anyway it looks like something bizarro with the selection scheme; one way to look at this is that the highlight isn't really a selection, but, if you set a valid real selection then it will override the original highlighted 'pseudo-selection'.  The original highlighting behaves like a selection in that a keypress will replace everything that's highlighted, but, not like a selection in that the selection methods reveal that there is no 'selection', see **UPDATE2** in the original post.

Can anyone help explain this behavior?  I'd like to build some more confidence in it before accepting this coincidental answer.

Thanks